# In R, indicate which columns in each row have the value "true"

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
> db
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    x     y     z     w
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I would like to create a new column, which for each row stores the columns which are equal to TRUE, so for example row #1 would be c(x,z) (e.g. in character format).

A dplyr solution would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `apply`

```
 df <-
   data.frame(
     x = c(T, T, T),
     y = c(F, F, F),
     z = c(T, F, F),
     w = c(T, F, T)
   )

 df$true_cols <- apply(df, 1, function(data)
   names(which(data == T)))
```

You look at each row, and find the columns which have their value set to "TRUE". This is gathered with the `which` function, which returns a number similar to an index. With the `name` function, it's possible to return the column name instead of the column position.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

We can `gather` into 'long' format, after creating a row id, then grouped by the 'rn', `paste` the elements in 'key' after subsetting through the 'val' column and `mutate` in 'db' by creating the 'new' column

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(db, 'rn') %>% 
      gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
      group_by(rn) %>%
      summarise(new = toString(key[val])) %>%
      pull(new) %>% 
      mutate(db, new = .)
#     x     y    z     w  new
#1 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE x, z
#2 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE x, z
#3 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE x, z
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be to get the index with `which` and use `tapply` to `paste` the elements

```
i1 <- which(as.matrix(db), arr.ind = TRUE)
tapply(names(db)[i1[,2]], i1[,1], paste, collapse=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R you can do it like the following.

```
db$new <- t(apply(db, 1, function(i) names(db)[i]))
#     x     y    z     w new.1 new.2
#1 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE     x     z
#2 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE     x     z
#3 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE     x     z
```

Note that `new` is an object of class `matrix`.

```
str(db)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ y  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ z  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ w  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ new: chr [1:3, 1:2] "x" "x" "x" "z" ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3"
  .. ..$ : NULL
```